# Express form handling without redirect. Has data without preventDefault, but redirects. Doesn't redirect with preventDefault, but doesn't have data

Tags: javascript, html, express, xmlhttprequest

Stuck in a catch 22 at the minute. I'm using custom form submission to avoid redirecting for when an express route is hit when posting a form, however, when not redirecting I lose the data I'm sending.

```
document.getElementById('playerSearchForm').onsubmit = function(_event)
{
    _event.preventDefault();

    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHR.addEventListener('load', function(event)
    {
        var res = JSON.parse(event.currentTarget.response);
    });

    XHR.addEventListener('error', function(event)
    {
        // error handling
    });

    XHR.open('POST', '/createGame');

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', document.getElementById("usernameInput").value);

    XHR.send(formData);
}
```

The above is how I'm submitting the form. If I have the `_event.preventDefault()` in there, then my page doesn't redirect, which is the intended result. However `_event.preventDefault` also stops the username being available on `req.body` in my express route. If I take out the `_event.preventDefault()` then I have access to the username in `req.body`, however the page redirects. Is there an alternate method of sending the data rather than using `FormData`, or is there something from within preventDefault I can call to ensure the data will be available?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've found a solution.

Part of my problem was that simply removing the `_event.preventDefault()` from the beginning meant that the form submission was occurring twice.

The other issue is that FormData is sent in a way that isn't stringifiable ([MDN Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files)). I've not dug into the docs, but I'm assuming the default body parsing I'm using can't deal with the FormData. To resolve this, I've removed the formData entirely and I'm simply sending the XHR request as follows:

```
XHR.send('username='+document.getElementById("usernameInput").value);
```

I'm not sure if this is correct practice, but it's working.